# nested array of json of nested arrays into single array of json

Tags: javascript

```
 var object = [{id:1, users:[{name:'john', name:'smith', name:'frank'}, {id:2, users:[{name:'lary'}, {name:'steve'}, {name:'joe'}]}]}]
```

**output:**

```
allUsers = [{name:'john'}, {name:'smith'}, {name:'frank'}, {name:’lary'}]
```

**need answer in javascript.** **and also  using lodash**

Comment: Hello, I am afraid that you are in a wrong place then. Try to do that on your own and if you fail, come back here for help, showing where you have failed.

Comment: This object have a strange structure...

Comment: thanks for you advice

Comment: Comment please if my answer did not satisfy you.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used lodash, but from the documentation I found a "**flatten**" -method, take a look here:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#flatten

> Flattens array a single level deep.

I hope that helps you.

**Edit**: Ok here is the code example (Your curly braces were little off so I fixed them in this example. I hope this is what you were looking for. 
But basically with map, get the users array from the individual object, then flatten the results after that.

```
var object = [
    {
        id:1,
        users: [{name:'john'}, {name:'smith'}, {name:'frank'}]
    }, 
    {
        id:2, 
        users: [{name:'lary'}, {name:'steve'}, {name:'joe'}]
    }
];

const flattenUsers = lodash.flatten(object.map(id => id.users));
console.log(flattenUsers);

/*
Output:
[ { name: 'john' },
  { name: 'smith' },
  { name: 'frank' },
  { name: 'lary' },
  { name: 'steve' },
  { name: 'joe' } ]
*/
```